# iOS CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation" wobble

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

I have the following code to rotate a compass. This code works fine on iOS 8 on both iPhone 6 and iPhone 5.

However, when trying this on iPhone 5S with iOS 7.1.2 the image is deviating from the Z axis, appearing to wobble / float around as it rotates.

As I say, this does not occur on the iPhone 5 or 6, both of which are running iOS 8.

Can anyone offer any advice?

```
float oldRad =  -manager.heading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
float newRad =  -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
theAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRad];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRad];
theAnimation.duration = 0.5f;
[compassimage.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateMyRotation"];
compassimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I realised this was an AutoLayout issue. Interestingly this issue started in iOS 6, and carried forwards to iOS 7. It doesn't seem to be impacting iOS 8 from what I can see!

A choice of fixes:-
1) Add centre x & y constraints
or
2) Disable autolayout

Both produce the desired outcome, although I am opting for number 1!